# Pub-Sub in python-freeopcua

Tags: python, publish-subscribe, opc-ua

I just started using freeopcua and am currently working on a client, that should do something (like print a string) when a certain node on the server changes its value. Apparently there is the [subscription class](https://python-opcua.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subscription.html), which should handles things like this.
But I just don't understand how it works... After I subscribed, as far as I can understand it, the events are given to the SubHandler, but how can I access the events?
How can I for example access the value, that has changed in the following code?

```
from opcua import Client

class SubHandler(object):

    def datachange_notification(self, node, val, data):
        print("Python: New data change event", node, val)

    def event_notification(self, event):
        print("Python: New event", event)

if __name__ == "__main__":

client = Client(some_url)

try:
    client.connect()

    obj = client.get_node(some_nodeID)

    handler = SubHandler()
    sub = client.create_subscription(500, handler)
    handle = sub.subscribe_data_change(obj)

finally:
    client.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value which has been changed in the `val` from `datachange_notification`